# Search a string in HTML code source

Tags: vb.net

Hello like the title says i want to search for a string in an html code source , this is my code :

```
 Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString("http://10.2.1.1/firewall_rules_edit.php?id=1")
    RichTextBox1.Text = reply
    If (reply.Contains("<input name=""disabled"" type=""checkbox"" id=""disabled"" value=""yes"" checked=""checked"" />")) Then
        Label1.Text = "Checked"
    End If
    If (reply.Contains("<input name=""disabled"" type=""checkbox"" id=""disabled"" value=""yes""  />")) Then
        Label1.Text = "UnChecked"
    End If
```

The label text doesn't change ...

I don't know where is the error :(

Comment: Is the router/firewall at `10.2.1.1` authenticated using a username or password? I've actually done this before; if you send me an email at the address in my profile I'll give you the source of my program.

Comment: Who downvoted this? @Amine can you first confirm that the `RichTextBox1` contains the text? Do you actually get a good response?

Comment: What is the actual content of `reply`? Use the debugger.

Comment: @KayNelson Yeah the richtextbox shows the code source

Comment: @cybermonkey Yup you got it right ! Okay sure i'll do that thanks :)

Comment: @AmineTagui If you visit the address in a browser, does it pop-up with a 'Requires username/password' dialog, or does it require you to sign-in using a login page?

Comment: @cybermonkey In the first usage yeah , but in my program i configured it in a way that it auto-connect and go to the page and then bring the code (i use a webbrowser to check if it auto logins etc)

Comment: What string are you using to login? Are you using `[username]:[password]@[address]` as in my answer (you need to pass the login information on every request, not just the first)?

Comment: @cybermonkey It needs to login only once , and here is the code i used ;
Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usernamefld").SetAttribute("value", "admin")


        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordfld").SetAttribute("value", "pfsense")

        'Clicki login
        For Each pElem As HtmlElement In elements
            If pElem.GetAttribute("value") = "Login" Then
                pElem.InvokeMember("Click")
            End If
        Next

Comment: @cybermonkey i would love to add the whole code in my question above so you can understand what i'm doing but it won't edit :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the router/firewall **requires authentication**.

If the device uses HTTP authentication, you can use`[username]:[password]@[address]` to pre-fill the login information.

For example if we assume the username is `admin` and the password is `1234`, we would do:

```
Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString("http://admin:1234@10.2.1.1/firewall_rules_edit.php?id=1")
```

Comment: i'll add the whole code so you can understand the program